Place in cell action via VBA code in excel
I need to place an image in a cell with VBA code so that I can right click on the image and under image options click show preview. This would allow the actual image to take up a small amount of space, but for any person later referencing the image, they can see it in full size. Most manual actions you can do in VBA code through some method, so I was wondering what the code behind this action was so I can replicate it in VBA.
I have seen many ways of putting an image in a cell via shapes.addpicture and formatting the size of the picture to be the same as the cell. I also recognize that if moveandsize is true then it will reformat as necessary if you change the size of the column and row. However this doesn't copy the functionality of the place in cell feature that you can use in excel if you have a large picture and right click and place in cell. This is the type of code for that:

Function LoadImage(ByVal Filename As String) As StdPicture
    With CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
        .LoadFile Filename
        Set LoadImage = .FileData.Picture
    End With
End Function

Private Sub CmdAttach_Click()
        Dim Pic_Path As String
        Pic_Path = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="JPG Images,*.jpg,Bitmap images,*.bmp,PNG Images,*.png", _
            Title:="Please select an image", MultiSelect:=False)
        If Dir(Pic_Path) <> "" Then
           Me.txtImageURL.Value = Pic_Path
           Me.Image1.Picture = LoadImage(Pic_Path)
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub CmdSubmit_Click()
        
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")
        Dim lr As Long
        Dim pic As Shape
        Dim cell As Range
        lr = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next
         Set cell = .Cells(lr + 1, "F")
         
         Set pic = .Shapes.AddPicture(Me.txtImageURL.Value, False, True, 1, 1, 100, 100)
        With pic
            .Left = cell.Left
            .Top = cell.Top
            .Height = cell.Height
            .Width = cell.Width
            .LockAspectRatio = False
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With
End Sub


